# Store settings in database to decide whether to force login?

Tags: database, authentication, setting

I'd like to mange my website dynamically. I already built database for storing user level and check access to pages successfully. Now I only want to decide whether to force login. Is it good to store pages in database along with its "needLogin" boolean field, so that each time user access a page, the database will decide whether to force login? Also I am confused to decide whether to force login in frontend or backend? Is there any better way?

Comment: You really think you will have a need to dynamically modify which pages require login?  That's not typical in my experience.

Comment: as I'd like to use my backend for several applications with different purposes in the future. Does it sound fine?

Comment: You're going to have to write all the application page logic by hand anyway for each page, so is it that hard to add a call to `requirelogin()` at the top of each page that requires user login?  Can you provide a use case where your method would be beneficial?

Comment: yes, to some aspects you're right. However, for example, if currently I force the users to log in before accessing multiple pages in both frontend and backend. Now I'd like to change a lot of the business logic, so I have to manually comes to each line of code and reconfigure instead of have them all configured at 1 place, with the GUI